# Keras error: LSTM.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'units'

Tags: python, keras, lstm

The code in TT_RNN is :

```
  def __init__(self,
                 tt_input_shape, tt_output_shape, tt_ranks,
                 activation='tanh',
                 recurrent_activation='hard_sigmoid',
                 use_bias=True,
                 kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform',
                 recurrent_initializer='orthogonal',
                 bias_initializer='zeros',
                 unit_forget_bias=True,
                 kernel_regularizer=None,
                 recurrent_regularizer=None,
                 bias_regularizer=None,
                 activity_regularizer=None,
                 kernel_constraint=None,
                 recurrent_constraint=None,
                 bias_constraint=None,
                 dropout=0.,
                 recurrent_dropout=0.,
                 debug=False,
                 init_seed=11111986,
                 **kwargs):
        super(TT_LSTM, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.units = np.prod(np.array(tt_output_shape))
        self.activation = activations.get(activation)
        self.recurrent_activation = activations.get(recurrent_activation)
        self.use_bias = use_bias

        self.kernel_initializer = initializers.get(kernel_initializer)
        self.recurrent_initializer = initializers.get(recurrent_initializer)
        self.bias_initializer = initializers.get(bias_initializer)
        self.unit_forget_bias = unit_forget_bias

        self.kernel_regularizer = regularizers.get(kernel_regularizer)
        self.recurrent_regularizer = regularizers.get(recurrent_regularizer)
        self.bias_regularizer = regularizers.get(bias_regularizer)
        self.activity_regularizer = regularizers.get(activity_regularizer)

        self.kernel_constraint = constraints.get(kernel_constraint)
        self.recurrent_constraint = constraints.get(recurrent_constraint)
        self.bias_constraint = constraints.get(bias_constraint)

        self.dropout = min(1., max(0., dropout))
        self.recurrent_dropout = min(1., max(0., recurrent_dropout))

        self.state_spec = InputSpec(shape=(None, self.units))
        self.debug = debug
        self.init_seed = init_seed

        tt_input_shape = np.array(tt_input_shape)
        tt_output_shape = np.array(tt_output_shape)
        tt_ranks = np.array(tt_ranks)
        self.num_dim = tt_input_shape.shape[0]
        self.tt_input_shape = tt_input_shape
        self.tt_output_shape = tt_output_shape
        self.tt_ranks = tt_ranks
        self.debug = debug
```

The code in MNISTSeq.py is :

```
if use_TT:
    Z = TT_LSTM(tt_input_shape=tt_input_shape, tt_output_shape=tt_output_shape, tt_ranks=tt_ranks,
    return_sequences=False, recurrent_dropout=.5)(X_mask)
    Out = Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid', kernel_regularizer=l2(1e-2))(Z)
else:
    Z = LSTM(units=rnn_size, return_sequences=False, recurrent_dropout=.5)(X_mask) # dropout=.5,
    Out = Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid', kernel_regularizer=l2(1e-2))(Z)
```

**error:**
**File "/content/TT_RNN/MNISTSeq.py", line 292, in** 
**Z = TT_LSTM(tt_input_shape=tt_input_shape, tt_output_shape=tt_output_shape, tt_ranks=tt_ranks,**
**File "/content/TT_RNN/TTRNN.py", line 682, in **init****
**super(TT_LSTM, self).**init**(**kwargs)**
TypeError: LSTM.**init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'units'**

Comment: You clas TT_LSTM inherits from LSTM and the constructor ( _ _ init _ _ ) needs a parameter called units, which you are not passing at all.

Comment: even when i am passing it taking units=1 for example : Z = TT_LSTM(tt_input_shape=tt_input_shape, tt_output_shape=tt_output_shape, tt_ranks=tt_ranks,units=1,
    return_sequences=False, recurrent_dropout=.5)(X_mask) i am getting this error: 
    raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: Can't set the attribute "units", likely because it conflicts with an existing read-only @property of the object. Please choose a different name.